# Avoiding the creation of fake users in order to exploit vulnerabilities

Tags: authentication, web, architecture

Generally, after the user is created, I require email confirmation before they can log in. But this can keep users stuck without email confirmation in the database. I was thinking about adding some banned email domains and captcha as well.

The question is, what do you generally do to avoid fake users? and do not leave dirt on the base of the system.

Comment: Usually the confirmation e-mail contains a link which is valid for certain hours, days. If the user is not confirmed the registration before the deadline then you can safely delete it from your database.

Comment: @PeterCsala I thought about that too, a hygiene routine for unconfirmed users. And maybe send it to a parallel database to study patterns and create new rules. It's a good idea for one more step, tks